# g_mass_storage select usb port

Tags: linux, usb-drive, arm, usb-device

I have nanopi neo air board with armbian buster image on it. I want to setup mass_storage on usb2 port. I successfully setup g_mass_storage for serving mass_storage device, but it work on default usb port, which is usb1 as i supposed. How  can i configure g_mass_storage for usb2? May be there are some other ways to get mass_storage on usb2 port?

UPD: I find in datasheet, that my board has only one OTG port. So, configure usb2 for mass_storage device mode impossible.